# Enable Back/Forward & Refresh Gestures in Universal Windows App (XAML)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm building a set of small internal apps for our business. A majority are web based tools. To provide easy access to all of the tools to all our staff. Previously I built small windows applications which are used currently. However, I'm looking to upgrade these to Universal Apps as we can better distribute future applications through our Microsoft Business Store.

Currently when placing a WebView into the UWP app, the app loads and functions as expected in terms of loading the WebView. However I cannot seem to find a means to implement Back / Forward navigation (previously this was a toggled option in the properties group) if a user navigates using Back/Forward on their mouse etc. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. No doubt it's something quite obvious I haven't spotted.

I was expecting the basic back / forward navigation to work out of the box (as is the case I have experienced previously when developing for other platforms)

The app I'm currently working on is using the UWP with XAML and C# and currently has the WebViews implemented using:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="https://app.domain.com"/>
```

within MainPage.xaml and no further modifications made to this app as it stands.

I regularly use SO as a guest to find answers to questions but I couldn't see a direct answer to this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: `WebView` class has built-in APIs that could Go Back/Forward. You could add some buttons and call them in the click event,

Answer (score 0):

The [WebView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-19041) has built-in APIs that could Go Back/Forward. You could add some buttons and call them in the click event.

Comment: Thanks Roy, I was hoping to be able to make use of our users's back/forward mouse nav buttons, rather than adding buttons to the interface. Is it possible to get the input from the back / forward inputs on a users mouse to navigate?

Comment: Do you mean using the mouse wheel?